# PowerAutomate use REST API turn on reporting site collection feature

Tags: rest, sharepoint-online, power-automate

We can turn this feature on via PowerShell PnP, but need to do it via PowerAutomate REST API call.

I have the following for our FLOW REST API call.

```
Site Address >> https://MYCO.sharepoint.com/sites/Sandbox
Method >> POST
URI >> /_api/web/features
Headers:
-accept : application/json;odata.metadata=none
-content-type : application/json

BODY:
{  
 "url": "https://MYCO.sharepoint.com/sites/Sandbox/_api/web/features/add('7094bd89-2cfe-490a-8c7e-fbace37b4a34')"
}
```

When I run the FLOW I get:

Error
Action 'Send_an_HTTP_request_to_SharePoint' failed

Invalid request.
clientRequestId: 690efeb4-ddce-49a2-b5d7-58e5e06db54a
serviceRequestId: 94ea649f-80ce-b000-973f-9686227e5f12

Answer (score 0):

Try giving entire thing in URI and leave body blank

```
Site Address >> https://MYCO.sharepoint.com/sites/Sandbox
Method >> POST
URI >> /_api/web/features/add('7094bd89-2cfe-490a-8c7e-fbace37b4a34')
Headers:
-accept : application/json;odata.metadata=none
-content-type : application/json

BODY:
```

Comment: Tried that, and error is now:

Feature '7094bd89-2cfe-490a-8c7e-fbace37b4a34' is Site-scoped, and cannot be added to the Web.
clientRequestId: d6dc6665-b0d7-4acb-bec1-821e9f341351
serviceRequestId: 9bbf669f-40b6-b000-2c62-8ff39d3c6cdb

Comment: Pleas check this https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/180121/feature-is-site-scoped-and-cannot-be-added-to-the-web-sharepoint-2010

Comment: Apologies...not following, as if I had to manually do this, it's at the site collection level.
The URI is site collection level as well.  I'm not trying to do anything at a web/sub-site level as this feature is for reporting on access logs within the entire site collection.

Comment: Please check this link - There is a chance like activated feature per site collection/site is enabled
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/a2af97c8-62db-4194-9fc5-cce6bc7e5d71/content-deployment-error-feature-is-site-scoped-and-cannot-be-added-to-the-web?forum=sharepointadminprevious

Comment: I don't think this is the case...these are brand new SP Online sites